# Unsupported number of argument for pure functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I have problem in angular2 (rc-1), I am passing an array of strings to my function by component binding. As soon as array length exceed 10 I have error:

`Unsupported number of argument for pure functions: 11`

Which sounds bit strange for me because of two reason:

- the array is single parameter
- why set limit of number of function params? (only thing I have in my mind is performance optimization to not use `arguments` keyword)

Component selector:

```
<tb-infinite-scroll
  [tbDataProperty]="[
    'prop1',
    'prop2',
    'prop3',
    'prop4',
    'prop5',
    'prop6',
    'prop7',
    'prop8',
    'prop9',
    'prop10',
    'prop11'
  ]"></tb-infinite-scroll>
```

In the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tb-infinite-scroll',
  inputs: [
    'dataProp:tbDataProperty',
  ],
  /*...*/
})

export class TbInfiniteScrollComponent {

  public dataProp:any = '';
```

Then inside component template:

```
<div *ngIf="sharedServices.typeOf(dataProp) === 'object'">
    <div class="tb-infinite-scroll__cell" *ngFor="let prop of dataProp">{{row[prop]}}</div>
</div>
```

Stack trace:

```
browser_adapter.js:77 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unsupported number of argument for pure functions: 11
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
    at PromiseCompleter.reject (zone.js:515)
    at eval (application_ref.js:295)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.js:45)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:216)
    at zone.js:571
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:36)
```

Any idea what causing that issue/any workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is moving the array to the class and just referring to the variable that holds the array an option?. I guess Angular monitors all variables for changes to update the binding when one value changes and to me it makes sense to limit the number in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect this to work:

```
<tb-infinite-scroll
  [tbDataProperty]="tbDataProperty"></tb-infinite-scroll>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  /*...*/
})

export class ParentComponent {
  tbDataProperty = [
    'prop1',
    'prop2',
    'prop3',
    'prop4',
    'prop5',
    'prop6',
    'prop7',
    'prop8',
    'prop9',
    'prop10',
    'prop11'
  ];
```

Comment: I guess you meant to define the array in parent component scope (.tb-infinite-scroll is current component) instead in the view? If yes then I did that and it works, so please edit your post and I'll accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That's what I meant, just didn't pay enough attention :-/